# How to query from datastore if the value is in the array struct in go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, datastore

I have two structs

```
type Parent struct {
    Text string
    Childs []ChildValue
}

type ChildValue struct {
    Name  string
    Value int32  `json:"value" datastore:"value" validate:"required,min=1,max=5"`
}
```

The value in childValue can be from 1 to 5. 
I want to be able to filter if value in array is more than 2

`query = query.Filter("childs.value =>", "2")`

It there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to get back the whole entity or specific  properties ?

Comment: The whole entity